# How to tell a difference between user-caused events and those "provoked" by OS

Tags: python, events, wxpython, exit

I am writing an app that has to go to system tray when user tries to close it.
Like Bit Torrent does. It just turns into a background process.

The trouble is that wx.EVT_CLOSE gets thrown even if OS asks your app to close.
So, if I use wx.EVT_CLOSE and user closes the program all is well - it goes into hiding, but if user then, with program running in background, goes to shut down, well, then, there is a problem obviously.

Well, that particular case may be solved by using:

```
if not self.IsShown(): e.Skip(); return
```

In the wx.EVT_CLOSE handler. But if  programs GUI is up and user goes for shut down, well, then, first instead of closing program just does self.Hide(). Then OS sees that program didn't close, so it asks it again to do so. And so on. A lot of trouble before OS forcefully kills it. And when it did, user's settings aren't saved.

My question is: Is there an easy way to tell when user requested closing directly and when OS asked the app to close?
I mean, is it supported by wx?
If not, I'll patch something up using signal module or someone here might have even better idea.